# Get key value of my JSON object Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My object

```
object1 ={
name: xxx,
Id: 212
}
```

I need a output like:

```
{
212:xxx
}
```

Can anyone help me to do it?

```
for(var key in object1) {
     if(object1.hasOwnProperty(key))
         {
             console.log( eachPeriod[key]);
         } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `key` of the object with a variable enclosed with brackets as `[Id]`.  The `convert()` function takes the object as an argument and assigns the value of `name` and `Id` to the corresponding variables by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).  Then, use those variables to construct the object.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'xxx',
  Id: 212
};

function convert ({ name, Id }) {
  return {
    [Id]: name
  };
}

console.log(convert(obj));
```